# neo4j-browser change bolt port for docker container

Tags: neo4j

I trying to startup a neo4j container for test data and use a separate bolt port.

```
docker run --env=NEO4J_AUTH=none
--env=NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*
--publish=7475:7474 --publish=7688:7687
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/conf-test:/conf
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/test-data:/data
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/plugins:/plugins
--name=neo4j-test neo4j
```

In `$HOME/neo4j/conf-test/neo4j.conf` file I have tried:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7688 # doesn't do anything
dbms.connector.bolt=:7688 # error also error with =7688
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7688 # does nothing
```

When I open my browser to `http://localhost:7475/browser/` it tries to connect to 7687
[image]

I use `:server connect` command to connect but it doesn't save the setting; though it connects fine. Everytime I refresh I have to enter them again.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't get this working with a config file since the docker container kept overwriting the file with its own settings.

Trick for me was to note that the `listen_address` and `advertised_address` variables [require a double underscore](https://github.com/neo4j/docker-neo4j/blob/master/src/3.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L37):-

`docker run \
    -e NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7688 \
    -e NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_advertised__address=:7688 \
    --rm \
    --name neo4j \
    --publish=7575:7474 \
    --publish=7688:7687 \
    neo4j`

> 2018-02-07 11:33:34.593+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7688.

This got me running on the correct port!

Answer (score 3):

Got it.

So I was missing `advertised_address`.

Leaving my `docker run` command alone,

I just add the following lines (or modify) to my `$HOME/neo4j/conf-test/neo4j.conf` file

```
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7688
dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address=:7688
```

Works for me.